# Any way to detect browser running through Terminal Services?

Tags: javascript, animation

I am working on a site that has some jquery based animation, and I was wondering if there is any way to detect if the site is running in browser that is being run in a terminal services (remote desktop) session so I can disable the animation?

I run through remote desktop quite often from remote locations and animations always annoy me, but I really like them when I'm not running through remote desktop. Is there any way to ease the pain without getting rid of animations all together?

I guess I could allow the user to turn them off, and have it store a cookie... but is there any way to do it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly impossible with JavaScript (way, way above the level JavaScript operates at).  It may be possible via something like Flash or ActiveX.

Edit: You will likely need something along the lines of what nVidia is using here: http://www.nvidia.com/Download/Scan.aspx?lang=en-us

Looks like a Java applet.

Answer (score 0):

If the site animation is annoying to you, you may want to take it off completely as it may be annoying to site users?

I would suggest not building in extra code to stop the site from displaying as it should, in some cases users of the site may be running terminal services themselves (creating a point of failure)

If the animation is some kind of intro you could have a "skip" feature that switches it off an use a cookie as you mention.

Comment: I believe he is saying that the site animation is annoying when viewed (by anyone) through Remote Desktop (because the animation isn't smooth), but that in the majority of cases it's fine.

Comment: @AaronSieb exactly... it's just like a lightbox popup or something takes 10 seconds instead of 2 because of all the refreshes and stuff like that

Comment: ok, I see. I would still stay this is easier to live with than the need to install an activeX control which will need to be installed for every user and may not get around some security protocols, with potential error/warning messages. The same goes for Java Applet, why have every user require the java runtime for the java applet.

Comment: not sure if the full java runtime is required for the java applet tho?